# Ruby on rails 6 app, how get friends from facebook who use same app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, omniauth-facebook, ruby-on-rails-6, facebook-friends

For authorization in the application, I use the login via the facebook, through the gem 'omniauth-facebook'. But stuck at the moment how to get a list of friends who also use my application(logged in), and display the result on a separate page. And share his resources in app (in sample bookmarks)

My gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'omniauth-facebook'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth['provider']
      user.uid = auth['uid']
      if auth['info']
        user.name = auth['info']['name'] || ""
        user.email = auth['info']['email'] || ""
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.where(:provider => auth['provider'],
    :uid => auth['uid']).first || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
  end

  def new
    redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_url, notice => 'Signed out'
  end
end
```

Bookmarks controller

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate
  before_action :set_bookmark, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :bookmark_owner]
  before_action :bookmark_owner, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.build(bookmark_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bookmark.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bookmark }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bookmark.update(bookmark_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @bookmark }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @bookmark.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bookmarks_url, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def bookmark_owner
    unless @bookmark.user_id == current_user.id
     flash[:notice] = 'Access denied as you are not owner'
     redirect_to bookmarks_path
    end
  end

  private
    def set_bookmark
      @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
    end

    def bookmark_params
      params.fetch(:bookmark, {}).permit(:name, :url)
    end
end
```

ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

  def authenticate
    redirect_to :login unless user_signed_in?
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    !!current_user
  end

end
```

I would be grateful for the help: what can be used for these purposes.

Comment: give it a try --
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_friends

Comment: you may refer here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends